# iostat %util for NFS mounted shares available?

Tags: nfs, iostat

Is there a way to calculate, from the client, the "% util" of NFS mounted disks?

I know with iostat, with locally mounted disks you can see %util

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s    ...  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    ...   9.04   20.00
```

Is there a way to see that from the client for an NFS mounted share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see "%util" (not clear what that would mean on an NFS mount), but you can get some useful information out of the nfsiostat command.

e.g.:

```
# nfsiostat /shared 5
nfs.example.com:/shared mounted on /shared:

   op/s     rpc bklog
   0.00        0.00
read:     ops/s        kB/s       kB/op     retrans     avg RTT (ms)    avg exe (ms)
          0.000       0.000       2.115        0 (0.0%)      14.461      14.624
write:    ops/s        kB/s       kB/op     retrans     avg RTT (ms)    avg exe (ms)
          0.000       0.000       7.049        0 (0.0%)       2.214       2.250
```

Comment: Looks like you're right--you can't.  You'd need to go to the box (or storage array) that's hosting the share and do an iostat there, thanks for the info.